# Is it necessary to introduce a new variable here? (MDN strings tutorial)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, variables

I'm a total newbie to computer science. I beg for patience. 
I've been following [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Useful_string_methods) and I'm on the first "active learning example."

```
const list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
list.innerHTML = '';
let greetings = ['Happy Birthday!',
                 'Merry Christmas my love',
                 'A happy Christmas to all the family',
                 'You\'re all I want for Christmas',
                 'Get well soon'];

for (let i = 0; i < greetings.length; i++) {
  let input = greetings[i];
  // Your conditional test needs to go inside the parentheses
  // in the line below, replacing what's currently there
  if (greetings[i]) {
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = input;
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  }
}
```

The goal is to modify the above code so the live output will display only the array values that include 'Christmas'. This is my solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < greetings.length; i++) {
  let input = greetings[i];
  if (greetings[i].indexOf('Christmas') !== -1) {
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = input;
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  }
}
```

This is the tutorial's solution (the same except for the introduction of a new variable - "result"):

```
for (let i = 0; i < greetings.length; i++) {
  let input = greetings[i];
  if (greetings[i].indexOf('Christmas') !== -1) {
    let result = input;
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = result;
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  }
```

Is it necessary to introduce "result", when it's just going to be changed to "input" anyways?

Comment: No, it's completely superfluous (and such a tutorial should really be at least using `const` for variables they aren't going to reassign)

Comment: They probably added it for pedagogical purposes, to indicate that it is the "result" of something, and not the "input". Technically it is not need, and would most likely be rejected in code review for being unnecessary.

Comment: They also should use `input.indexOf('Christmas')` -- one of the reasons to assign a variable is to avoid having to repeat the more complex expression.

Comment: @Automatico You're right about the purpose. If you look at the coding examples on that page, they all use the `input` and `result` variables -- they're part of a consistent pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra variable is completely unnecessary and is only there for stylistic purposes. Usually if you define a variable that is only used once like their `result` variable it's for a long, complex expression that could be confusing.